# Custom file input using jquery restrict the user file types and filename if the user click check box it input file disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently working on file upload

1. where the user can upload only **jpeg** and **pdf** files n the text field it has to show the filename.
2. less than 5mb
3. If user click the checkbox it should not allow to atthach file it should be disabled

   Here I was confused how to set the filetypes, restrict size & how to disabled.

Here is my jquery code till now i tried

```
     var $preview = $(".preview");
//var $acceptdiv = $("#accept_div");
//$acceptdiv.hide();
$preview.hide();
$(".check").on("change", function(){     
    var filename = this.value;
    var files = this.files;
    var URL = window.URL||window.webkitURL;
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
    $preview.attr("href", url);
    $preview.show();
    //$acceptdiv.show();
    document.getElementById('file_name').value = filename;
    $("#file_name").prop("disabled", true);
});
/* health infor addmore ends here*/

$(document).on('click', ".accpt_chk", function() {
    alert("check");
    if($('.accpt_chk').prop(':checked')) {
            $('.checkfile').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('.checkfile').prop('enabled', false);
            //$(this).closest("#btn_selct").removeClass('cst_select').addClass('cst_select_dis');
            //$('#btn_selct').hasClass('.cst_select ').remove().addClass('.cst_select_dis');
        }   
    //$('.qq-upload-button').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/02kfzfz6/)

Kindly please helpme

Thanks in advnace

Comment: I found the solution for 3 point but I am thinking how to add css class for the disabled button

Answer (score 0):

1.To check whether a checkbox is selected or not you have use `.is(':checked')`
like `if ($('.accpt_chk').is(':checked')) {}`
2. To add an attribute you can use `.attr('name','value')`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gndcdcvp/1/)

part of updated Js

```
$(document).on('click', ".accpt_chk", function() {
  if ($('.accpt_chk').is(':checked')) {
    $('.checkfile').attr('disabled', 'true')
  } else {
    $('.checkfile').removeAttr('disabled')
    $('.checkfile').prop('enabled', false);
    $(this).closest("#btn_selct").removeClass('cst_select').addClass('cst_select_dis');
    //$('#btn_selct').hasClass('.cst_select ').remove().addClass('.cst_select_dis');
  }
  //$('.qq-upload-button').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help can you please tell me how to add class cst_select_dis once the user click the hide user checkbox and please help me for the first and second

Comment: I got the solution for adding class and removing class for button please help me for filetype and file size

Comment: @J Santhosh thanks for the effort I want to see the file name in the text box rest everything was wokring kindly please help me & I have a link call view if the user click that it should open in  a new window that is also not working

Comment: @Mahadevan, select the proper file (pdf.jpeg and less than 5 mb ), you will see the file name in text box. and `I have a link call view if the user click that it should open in a new window that is also not working` for this you have to search the #SO or ask new question

Comment: thanks santhosh can you please look this i have forgot to add if i want to edit the question i can do know please do me the favour